# XMLHttpRequest upload progress inaccurate percentage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I have this code that works fine inside my electron app. It will manage the file upload. The request is processed by an embedded php server that on macOS is the default php development server and on windows is localized inside a folder that will contain the php binary and will be part of the final build of my app. 
I've implemented the `XMLHttpRequest` progress to display a bootstrap 4 progress bar to the user, and it's supposed to track the upload status. I've noticed that every time I will upload a file, no matter the size, the percentage will become 100% also if the file upload is in progress. Is there a way to make it more accurate? I'm using a custom class that will rely on the ftp php functions to contact the server and then upload files, those files are mostly videos and the max dimension can be also of 400/500MB so I need an accurate percentage to avoid that the user abort the process or close the app because he think that it's crashed.

Here is the js code I'm using to prototype the app:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
const bsCustomFileInput = require('bs-custom-file-input');

$(document).ready(function(){

  bsCustomFileInput.init();

  $('#file-uploader').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('#file-uploader')[0]);
    //formData.append('uploaded_file', $('#file-uploader')[0]);
    $('.modal').modal('show');

    $.ajax({
      xhr: function(){
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
          if(evt.lengthComputable){
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
            console.log(percentComplete);
            $('.progress-bar').css('width',percentComplete+"%");
            $('.progress-bar').html(percentComplete+"%");
              if(percentComplete === 100){

              }
          }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
      },
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/requestsController.php',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
        console.log(response);
      }
    });

  });


});
</script>
```